# UDP socket state list?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-kernel, udp, ip

I'm currently writing a script pulling data from `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/udp` and I need to translate the connection states from their hex code into something meaningful.

Example content:

```
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode ref pointer drops
  37: 00000000:2710 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 862948 2 ffff8800109dbac0 0
  54: 00000000:00A1 00000000:0000 07 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 2055110 2 ffff8800109db780 0
```

So far I've turned up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5992274/1064767) which pointed me to the relevant kernel header file, but there is not a matching `udp_states.h` or anything in `udp.h` or `ip.h`.

Where can I find a list of connection states for UDP sockets?

Answer (score 6):

UDP 'connections' are stateless. From the [iptables manual](http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html#UDPCONNECTIONS):

> UDP connections are in themselves not stateful connections, but rather stateless. There are several reasons why, mainly because they don't contain any connection establishment or connection closing; most of all they lack sequencing. Receiving two UDP datagrams in a specific order does not say anything about the order in which they were sent. It is, however, still possible to set states on the connections within the kernel.

See this [udp programming tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150111145442/http://www.codingtree.com/c/c-sockets-connectionless.html) which also helps explain why a command like `ss -ua` shows an udp server socket as UNCONN (aka CLOSE for tcp connections).

To sum up, I do believe the udp 'states' shown in /proc/net are recycled from tcp connection states, but they have a slightly different meaning.

Comment: I found an iptables rule using `ctstate NEW` for `udp dpt:ntp`; does that make any sense then?

Answer (score 4):

On the Xubuntu I am currently looking at these states are in

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24/include/net/tcp_states.h
```

You might find that UDP just reuses the same enumeration, take a look inside of [`/usr/src/linux/net/ipv4/udp.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/udp.c) and look for usages of `sk_state`.

The function `udp4_format_sock()` actually produces the output you are looking at.

Comment: That *seems* to be the case, but it still doesn't make sense to me since `07` translates to `TCP_CLOSE`.

Comment: @6EQUJ5, could please include the link to the code path from Xubuntu. Thanks.
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/udp.c